# How to get external storage path in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions

I need to get external sd card path for that im using 'external_path' package but im getting 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference'. I did lot of r&d on this but haven't found any solution.

```
UPDATE Surface(name=SurfaceView[com.pinciat.external_path_example/com.pinciat.external_path_example.MainActivity])/@0x9f94b11, mIsProjectionMode = false
W/ContextImpl(15102): Failed to ensure /storage/9016-4EF8/Android/data/com.pinciat.external_path_example/files: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code -22)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at com.pinciat.external_path.ExternalPathPlugin.getExternalStorageDirectories(ExternalPathPlugin.kt:52)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at com.pinciat.external_path.ExternalPathPlugin.onMethodCall(ExternalPathPlugin.kt:42)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$2j2MERcK825A5j1fv5sZ7xB2Iuo.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
E/MethodChannel#external_path(15102):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
D/DecorView[](15102): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
E/flutter (15102): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
E/flutter (15102):  at com.pinciat.external_path.ExternalPathPlugin.getExternalStorageDirectories(ExternalPathPlugin.kt:52)
E/flutter (15102):  at com.pinciat.external_path.ExternalPathPlugin.onMethodCall(ExternalPathPlugin.kt:42)
E/flutter (15102):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/flutter (15102):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/flutter (15102):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/flutter (15102):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$2j2MERcK825A5j1fv5sZ7xB2Iuo.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (15102):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/flutter (15102):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter (15102):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
E/flutter (15102):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
E/flutter (15102):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
E/flutter (15102):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (15102):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
E/flutter (15102):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
E/flutter (15102): )
E/flutter (15102): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
message_codecs.dart:653
E/flutter (15102): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:315
E/flutter (15102): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15102): #2      ExternalPath.getExternalStorageDirectories
external_path.dart:22
E/flutter (15102): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15102): #3      _MyAppState.getPath
main.dart:35
E/flutter (15102): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15102):
```

This is the package i'm using [external_path](https://pub.dev/packages/external_path).

could any one help me on this ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i really don't think people nowadays still use SD card :)

Comment: There is a package called `path_provider`. https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider.
You can just use the `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method.